# Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:))

Tags: swift, swiftui, async-await

I am building an app with Swift and SwiftUI. In MainViewModel I have a function who call Api for fetching JSON from url and deserialize it. this is made under async/await protocol.
the problem is the next, I have received from xcode the next comment : "Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates." in this part of de code :

```
func getCountries() async throws{
    
        countries = try await MainViewModel.countriesApi.fetchCountries() ?? []
}
```

who calls this one:

```
func fetchCountries() async throws -> [Country]? {

    guard let url = URL(string: CountryUrl.countriesJSON.rawValue ) else {
        print("Invalid URL")
        return nil
    }
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    do {
        let (json, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: urlRequest)

        if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Country].self, from: json) {
            debugPrint("return decodeResponse")
            return decodedResponse
        }
    } catch {
            debugPrint("error data")
        
    }
    return nil

}
```

I would like to know if somebody knows how I can fix it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First fetch the data asynchronously and then assign the result to the property on the main thread

```
func getCountries() async throws{    
    let fetchedData = try await MainViewModel.countriesApi.fetchCountries()
    await MainActor.run {
        countries = fetchedData ?? []
    }
}
```

Off topic perhaps but I would change `fetchCountries()` to return an empty array rather than nil on an error or even better to actually throw the errors since it is declared as throwing.

Something like

```
func fetchCountries() async throws -> [Country] {
    guard let url = URL(string: CountryUrl.countriesJSON.rawValue ) else {
        return [] // or throw custom error
    }
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    let (json, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: urlRequest)

    return try JSONDecoder().decode([Country].self, from: json)
}
```

Answer (score 14):

There are two ways to fix this. One, you can add the `@MainActor` attribute to your functions - this ensures they will run on the main thread. Docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mainactor. However, this could cause delays and freezing as the **entire block** will run on the main thread. You could also set the variables using `DispatchQueue.main.async{}` - see [this article from Hacking With Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/9/4/back-to-the-main-thread-dispatchqueuemain). Examples here:

```swift
@MainActor func getCountries() async throws{
   ///Set above - this will prevent the error
   ///This can also cause a lag
   countries = try await MainViewModel.countriesApi.fetchCountries() ?? []
}
```

Second option:

```swift
func getCountries() async throws{
  DispatchQueue.main.async{
   countries = try await MainViewModel.countriesApi.fetchCountries() ?? []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@MainActor
func getCountries() async throws {
        countries = try await MainViewModel.countriesApi.fetchCountries() ?? [] }
```

This should fix this issue.

Just need to add `MainActor` right before the function starts.