How to ensure non-async portion of async function executes before view assignment?
I have following (simplified) model:
struct PostDetailResponse: Codable {
    var post_detail: PostDetailContent
}

struct PostDetailContent: Codable {
    var userHasLiked: Bool?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case userHasLiked = "user_has_liked"
    }
}
// Full data structure used within the application
struct PostDetailed {
    var userHasLiked: Bool?
}
extension PostDetailed {
    mutating func update(with postDetailContent: PostDetailContent) {
        self.userHasLiked = postDetailContent.userHasLiked
    }
}

It is populate via selectPost which is defined in the viewmodel:
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import KeychainAccess
import Kingfisher
class PostDetailedPageViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var postDetailed: PostDetailed
    @Published var isLoading = false
    @Published var errorMessage: String?
    
    init(postDetailed: PostDetailed) {
        self.postDetailed = postDetailed
    }
    
    func selectPost(postID: String) async {
        print("This should happen FIRST")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.isLoading = true
        }
        
        let keychainHelper = KeychainHelperUtility(service: "com.venividi.app")
        
        do {
            guard let accessToken = try keychainHelper.getAccessToken() else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.errorMessage = "Error retrieving access token"
                    self.isLoading = false
                }
                return
            }
            // Using async/await to call the API service
            let data = try await APIGetService(token: accessToken).invokeGetUserPostDetailedLambda(postID: postID)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.isLoading = false
                if let data = data {
                    self.updatePostDetail(with: data)
                } else {
                    self.errorMessage = "No data received from the server"
                }
            }
        } catch {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.isLoading = false
                // Adjust error message based on the type of error
                if let error = error as? URLError {
                    self.errorMessage = "Networking error: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                    print(self.errorMessage as Any)
                    print("we fuckin up")
                } else {
                    self.errorMessage = "Error: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                    print("we fuckin uppp")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func updatePostDetail(with data: Data) {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(DateFormatter.iso8601MilliSeconds)
        
        do {
            let jsonResponse = try decoder.decode(PostDetailResponse.self, from: data)
            let postDetail = jsonResponse.post_detail
            print("we got all of the detail and its here \(postDetail)")
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // Update the content and locationsJson directly from the decoded data

                self.postDetailed.userHasLiked = postDetail.userHasLiked
                print("This should happen SECOND")

            }
        } catch {
            print("there was an issue")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.errorMessage = "Failed to decode post details: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                print(self.errorMessage ?? "Failed")
            }
        }
    }
}

The view runs the selectPost in .onAppear since this page is navigated to from a list of a variety of posts.
struct PostDetailedPageView: View {

    @StateObject var viewModel: PostDetailedPageViewModel
    
    init(postDetailed: PostDetailed) {
        _viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: PostDetailedPageViewModel(postDetailed: postDetailed)
    }
    
    @State private var isMapExpanded = false
    @State private var isLiked = false  // State to manage the like button

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                // Display the number of likes with heart button
                HStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        isLiked.toggle()
                        
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: isLiked ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
                            .foregroundColor(isLiked ? .red : .gray)
                    }
                    Text("\(viewModel.postDetailed.likesCount ?? 0) likes")
                        .font(.caption)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                }

            }
            .onAppear {
                Task {
                    await viewModel.selectPost(postID: viewModel.postDetailed.postID)
                    print("This should happen THIRD \(viewModel.postDetailed.userHasLiked ?? nil)")
                    if let userHasLiked = viewModel.postDetailed.userHasLiked {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            isLiked = userHasLiked
                            print("isLiked is now set to \(isLiked)")
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("userHasLiked is nil")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .navigationTitle("Post Details")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }

}

I am expecting the order of operations to follow those described in the print statements:

This should happen FIRST
This should happen SECOND
This should happen THIRD

If this worked in the right order, we would be assigning the view's @State private var isLiked to the value properly populated into viewModel.postDetailed.userHasLiked from updatePostDetail. Unfortunately, the order occurs as follows:

This should happen FIRST
This should happen THIRD
This should happen SECOND

This leads to isLiked always being assigned nil. I don't understand why the isLiked = userHasLiked is running before updatePostDetail has finished executing. The latter is tucked inside of an async function selectPost which we are explicitly saying to await. Why would the isLiked = userHasLiked run before all parts of selectPost - including the nested updatePostDetail - are completed?
How can I ensure this works properly? I have thought to simply use viewModel.postDetailed.userHasLiked directly within the view, but then I lose out on the benefits of using the @State variable in the view and this seems like bad practice.
Note I have ensured that the data is being properly populated and called from the database via invokeGetUserPostDetailedLambda, so you can assume this works properly. Also note the reason for the mutating func update... portion of the model results from it in actuality having more values, but I have stripped these out to focus on the problem.

Don't combine DispatchQueue with async/await concurrency. Get rid of all of the DispatchQueue.main.async calls. The whole point of async/await is that you can write linear code. Don't use an unstructured Task in onAppear, use a .task The reason that things aren't happening in the order you want is because you are dispatching then asynchronously but the main queue is already processing your code and there is no preemption.  You are simply dispatching code to happen "some time"

If I get rid of the DispatchQueue.main.async I get purple warnings from the simulator of Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.. How can I avoid this error without using these calls? Or would this get resolved by having removed .onAppear?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74318973/9223839

@Runeaway3 – Using DispatchQueue.main.async {…} is not the right way to solve the “publishing changes from background threads” warning. Generally you would isolate the published properties to the main actor. Or, as advised by Apple in Swift concurrency: Update a sample app and Discover concurrency in SwiftUI, one would generally isolate the whole ObservableObject to the main actor.

Does it not make more senes to use MainActor.run{...}? This way I can target just the setting of the UI-related structs to the mainthread? Why mark the entire ObservableObject as @MainActor? It does things related to eventually modifying UI updates, but wouldn't it be more efficient to only dictate that the actual setting of UI values be MainActor, and enable whichever-most-optimal-thread is selected by the concurrency system to run the rest?

You can isolate the published properties to the main actor by adding @MainActor to their declaration.

@Runeaway3 – using MainActor.run {…} works, but it is a very GCD-way of thinking of it, placing the burden on the caller to make sure you get it on the correct thread, generating run-time errors if you fail to do so. By isolating the properties to the main actor, you enjoy compile-time validation of your code. Watch that “Update sample app” video, and it walks you from GCD to MainActor.run and finally retiring that in favor of the actor isolation pattern. In SwiftUI concurrency, we try to let the compiler check our code rather than relying on runtime failures.
